# Mapping from array to call Function constructor fails

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapping

I need to do something like this:

```
Array.from(["xx","aa"], Function, this)
```

Which should return an array with two anonymous functions like this:

```
[ function anonymous(){ xx }, function anonymous() { aa } ]
```

However the array I get is:

```
[ function anonymous(xx){ 0 }, function anonymous(aa) { 1 } ]
```

I've looked at the documentation for `Array.from()` and seems like when it maps the array it calls `callback(this[i], i, this)` where `this` is the array being mapped and `i` is the current element index.

I can limit the parameters sent by doing something like this:

```
Array.from(["xx","aa"], function(elem) { Function(elem) } , this)[0]
```

However, this returns `undefined` and doesn't return any functions!

Any ideas on how to make it not send index of array using this syntax:     `Array.from(["xx","aa"], Function, this)[0]`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You forgot the return - `function(elem) { return Function(elem) }` or use an arrow function

Comment: So, `xx` and `aa` in your example are function bodies (chunks of executable code) in a string form? And you're trying to eval them on the fly?

Comment: @georg, exactly!!

Comment: @OriDrori This actually works. Thank you. Is there, however, another way to do it (tell map() not to send index parameter) without having to use the `function()` syntax or arrow functions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you want to exactly achieve, however can't you just `Array#map` over that array?

```js
const r = [() => 'foo', () => 'boo'].map((f) => () => f);

console.log(r);
r.forEach((f) => console.log(f()()));
```

Comment: This is not what I want. I need to be able to execute the code inside the function. "xx" and "aa" are just examples. They would be replaced by stuff like, `x=something`

Comment: @user00239123 I just did execute the code inside array. If it would be a function instead of a string, all you had to do would be to add additional braces `()` to call it.